# Manipulation of Ruby JSON Parantheses

Tags: ruby, json

I have a program in Ruby/Sinatra that retrieves the data as following format:

```
{
    "label": "root",
    "children": [
        {
            "label": "london"
        },
        {
            "label": "hong kong"
        }
    ]
}
```

However I want to respond that data to Front-End with the following format:

```
[
     {
         "label": "root",
         "children": [
             {
                 "label": "london"
             },
             {
                 "label": "hong kong"
             }
         ]
     }
]
```

Is there any way to manipulate that data? Thank you for help..

Comment: Just wrap it in an Array... `[json]`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit i'm not sure that you're being sarcastic or not.